# Are there any good Mongodb GUI clients?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, database, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good MongoDB GUI client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196136/what-is-a-good-mongodb-gui-client)

Are there any good Mongodb GUI clients for Ubuntu? (Preferably that will run on Ubuntu 11.04.) I found one [(`JmongoBrowser`)](http://edgytech.com/jmongobrowser/) but I'm not that impressed by its performance. It works but would like to know if anyone knows about something better and/or more stable.