# What is a good MongoDB GUI client?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, database, client, mongodb

I've been using [Rockmongo](http://rockmongo.com/) on Windows - it's a php based web tool. But on Ubuntu (12.04) it's behaving funny - queries timing out often - and I'm looking for better clients. Does anyone know anything good for MongoDB on Ubuntu?

Comment: I've been maintaining an up-to-date wiki-style list of MongoDB admin UIs, including cross-platform open-source ones, in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310242/visually-managing-mongodb-documents-and-collections).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One thing I know of (but don't like the interface very much) is [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/), which is a desktop, not browser-based application. Here's a screenshot:

[image: a screenshot of UMongo]

So far I've been using [MonjaDB](http://www.jumperz.net/index.php?i=2&a=0&b=9) - it's an Eclipse plug-in, and Eclipse is my IDE anyway. I like it; it seems to have all the features I used to use in [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/).

Here's a screenshot from MonjaDB (there are more on his website, as well as some instructions):

[image: a screenshot of MonjaDB]

To install it, you obviously need Eclipse (which you can get from the Ubuntu repositories). Once you've done that you need to go to the Help-> Install New Software... and then add [this update site](http://www.jumperz.net/update/). Although I like it, I don't think many people will switch IDE's just for a GUI for Mongo (although I could be mistaken).

Both UMongo and MonjaDB have their source code is on GitHub.

Comment: Umongo's site is gone.

Answer (score 69):

## [Robo 3T](http://www.robomongo.org/) (formerly known as RoboMongo)

> Shell-centric cross-platform open source MongoDB management tool (i.e. Admin GUI).
>
> [It] embeds the same JavaScript engine (based on Mozilla SpiderMonkey), that powers MongoDB's mongo shell. It means that you can reuse your existing skills of MongoDB Shell in Robomongo.

**Edit**

Some more info:

- It's available for [Linux, OSX and Windows](http://www.robomongo.org/download).
- Regarding Linux, there are packages available in the .rpm (Fedora, CentOS, openSUSE), .deb (Debian, Ubuntu) and .tar.gz formats.
- It is free (as in Speech); you can access its GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo).

Comment: Be sure to check `View -> Explorer` once the program is launched for the first time -- or you will be lost looking for the list of databases, like I was.

Comment: This app is badly written. Doesn't work on Windows 7 as of today (build 0.8.5). First I thought it can't connect to local server. Then I googled and found here I need to open Explorer. And now it shows I have no collections in db.

Comment: @ruslan: You sir made me spend the last 15 minutes reviving an old windows 7 VM (64 bits SP 1), installing MongoDB (3.0.4) and RoboMongo (0.8.5) in it, just to verify there are no problems whatsoever. I also successfully connected to a remote MongoDB server (running on Ubuntu Server). Of everything you said, the only thing I agree with is that not showing the explorer by default is a bad UX design choice. But calling this application "badly written" is, IMHO, a gross exaggeration.

Comment: @rsenna I'm on Mongo 3.1.2. Perhaps that's the reason why it's not working but I wouldn't expect that because the protocol is backward compatible. Let me know if you want me to test new build or something.

Comment: @ruslan RoboMongo doesn't work with Mongo 3.0 and above. We recently had to switch to MongoChef because of that.

Comment: Regarding MongoDB 3 support: "Robomongo 0.9.0 RC2 supports MongoDB 3.x and WiredTiger engine. For any found issues, please report to https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/520 ".

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't run on Ubuntu. `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"`. And yes, I have QT installed.

Comment: @Cerin: which version of Ubuntu, and which version of RoboMongo?

Answer (score 13):

You can check out [mongobooster](http://mongobooster.com). MongoBooster is a shell-centric cross-platform GUI tool for MongoDB v2.2-3.2, which provides update-in-place, Lodash & Moment.js integration, ES6 syntax support and true intellisense experience.

MongoBooster has the following features:

1. MongoBooster offers true IntelliSense experience. The build-in language service knows all possible completions, methods, properties, variables, key words, even the MongoDB collection names, field names and operators. The IntelliSense suggestions will pop up as you type.
2. In the script editor, parameter hints will pop up as you're typing a method invocation.Handy date range snippets, SQL to MongoDB conversion snippets...
3. The mouse hover will show many useful information, such as types of symbols, function definition, type information and document.
4. Matching brackets will be highlighted as soon as the cursor is near one of them.
5. Everything MongoBooster can do is in the Command Palette. See it by using shortcuts CTRL-SHIFT-P
6. SSH tunneling for MongoDB connections
7. Simple management of shards and replica sets
8. There is a free license with some limitations.

Disclaimer: I work for MongoBooster.

[image: mongobooster_main_screen]

Comment: I downloaded this tool and ran one aggregation with it. It failed (No documents returned). Next! I don't have time for tools that hit bugs inside of 5 minutes. The aggregation worked fine in Robomongo incidentally.

Answer (score 10):

[**3T MongoChef**](http://3t.io/mongochef/) is a multi-platform desktop GUI for MongoDB and runs also on Ubuntu. It’s a commercial tool but it’s free for personal and non-commercial use.

It has lots of useful features, e.g. in-place data editing or a drag&drop search query builder (www.3t.io/mongochef/mongochef-whats-new).

[image: **Screenshot of 3T MongoChef on Ubuntu**]

Comment: The only app out of entire list that works with Mongo 3.1.x.

Comment: [MongoBooster](http://mongobooster.com) works on 3.1/3.2 too, as well as [Mongo Management Studio](http://www.litixsoft.de).

Comment: Very important: also works on MongoDB 3.2!

Comment: This is owned by Studio3T, the same people who develop RoboMongo? Why make competing products?

Answer (score 6):

#### Robo 3T

Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) is the free lightweight GUI for MongoDB enthusiasts. Robo 3T (*robo3t-snap*) is packaged as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. robo3t-snap is packaged with an embedded MongoDB shell.

To install Robo 3T open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install robo3t-snap
```

---

#### Studio 3T

[Studio 3T](https://www.robomongo.org/) (formerly MongoChef) is a professional GUI and IDE for MongoDB. Studio 3T is available in Core, Pro, and Enterprise editions. The Core edition is always free for non-commercial use.

Features:

- Autocomplete queries with IntelliShell
- Drag and drop fields to visually build queries
- Use SQL to query MongoDB
- Build aggregation queries stage by stage
- Generate driver code in 5 languages
- Multiple ways to import & export, including SQL migration
- Automate repetitive MongoDB tasks like imports
- And so much more...

Answer (score 5):

## [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)

> The GUI for MongoDB. Visually explore your data. Run ad hoc queries in seconds. Interact with your data with full CRUD functionality. View and optimize your query performance. Available on Linux, Mac, or Windows. Compass empowers you to make smarter decisions about indexing, document validation, and more.

- **Official** GUI from MongoDB.
- Feature rich: provides not only direct data access, but also real-time server statistics, visual explain plans, index maintenance, aggregation pipelines UI.
- It's available for [Linux (RedHat, Ubuntu), OSX and Windows](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass).
- Community version is free (as in Beer, not FLOSS), and lacks some features. Regarding the commercial version: "MongoDB Compass is available as part of our subscriptions, as are the Readonly Edition and Isolated Edition."

Comment: Just a note, you have to select "Community Edition" to download it without giving Mongo all your details.

Comment: And it segfaults on Ubuntu 18.10 :-(

Comment: @tudor Sorry to hear that. I was able to use it in Windows and OSX with success, will try it in Ubuntu. MongoDB Compass is still pretty much a work in progress: slow to startup, kind of rough at the edges, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

## [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/FAQ)

There is [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/FAQ) (a web-based php client), but I can't tell how good it is.

Comment: RockMongo is mentioned in the question and it's also dead now. :(

Answer (score 2):

[qMongoFront](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qmongofront/) is a QT based MongoDB GUI client on linux.It is totally free and opensouce.

Answer (score 1):

Show Tadpole DB hub.
Tadpole is web base db client tools.
https://github.com/hangum/TadpoleForDBTools/wiki

support mongoDB, mariaDB, MySQL, MSSQL, apache hive, pgsql, sqlite... others

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

there is free [NoSQL Viewer](http://www.spviewer.com/nosqlviewer.html) GUI tool for MongoDB and other NoSQL databases that provides convenient interface to data and supports a lot of useful features

Comment: why nobody upvote this answer... i wonder..

Answer (score 1):

[Mongo Management Studio](http://www.litixsoft.de/english/mms/)

It is a cross platform tool with a pretty ui. The community edition is for free. The professional edition has more features and includes support.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not include a GUI-style administrative interface. But Actually I would recommend to check Admin UIs listed in [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org) which is more helpful & lists are updated.

For more Information, please check this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/#admin-uis)

Comment: There are some good GUI's in the list, but most don't support Ubuntu.

Answer (score -3):

NoSQL Viewer is a free tool that supports MongoDB and other NoSQL databases.

NoSQL Viewer is available [here](http://www.spviewer.com/nosqlviewer.html).

Comment: Thanks, but NoSQL Viewer has already been proposed in a previous answer.